# Why printing in Google chrome of html cv made with pagedown in R leaves empty spaces in pages?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pagedown

While making CV in Rmarkdown using pagedown:

RMarkdown > From Template > HTML Resume > OK > save

Lijia Yu's resume opens up. I knit it, and open the HTML file in browser, some written material goes to another page leaving space in the first page (see the attached image). Why is this happening?
[image]

Comment: What exactly does your markdown file look like? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I did not write my own markdown document. I simply opened R, went to Rmarkdown, then "From templates" to "HTML Resume". The in built resume of  Lijia Yu's opens up. I tried to knit it and print it in chrome.

Comment: What version of pandoc do you have installed? And what version of RStudio? And what version of chrome?

Comment: R version 3.5.2, chrome  Version 79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (32-bit)

Comment: Are you using a local webserver to view the HTML file in your browser?